# Cython and clang on mac, "Python.h not found"

Tags: python, clang, cython, cythonize

I'm running clang on mac to compile a c file created by running a very simple program through cython, but the compiler always give me a "Python.h not found" fatal error. I've tried every solution I could find, reinstalling python 3.9, using the -I/path/to/headerfile method, and rewriting the include statement in the code to contain the full filepath, but nothing has worked. When I do include the full filepath, I get fatal error: 'cpython/initconfig.h' file not found. What could the issue possibly be, and how would I fix it? The program itself works fine in the standard python interpreter, pyinstaller, and nuitka.

Comment: I can't help you for Mac, but on a linux system you'd need to install one of the `libpython-dev` packages (for 3.9, on Ubuntu/Debian, `libpython3.9-dev`)

Answer (score 1):

Today I needed to embed Python into a C application developed on XCode with Clang compiler, and I've met the same problems and solved them. Let me share the tips:

## 1. Python not found error

You should install a Python framework to your MacOS, and attach it into `Frameworks and Libraries` project settings tab. Also, specify it's path in `Framework Search Paths` inside `Build Settings` tab if XCode hasn't done it automatically.

## 2. Undefined symbols / Implicit declaration errors

Verify you're using a modern version of Python framework. Versions prior to 3.6 had different ABI which leads to the mentioned errors.

## 3. cpython/initconfig.h file not found

Versions prior to ~3.9 had some header inclusion problem for the `cpython/initconfig.h` file (issues [40642](https://bugs.python.org/issue40642), [39026](https://bugs.python.org/issue39026)).

---

Check the builds of Python that your OS currently has. I found Pythons installed in the following paths:

```
# Default 2.7 MacOSX installation is here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/

/Library/Frameworks/
```

Or install a recent Python version. I recommend using "universal binary" build, [see the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html).